# Converting to long panel data format with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, panel-data

I have a DataFrame where rows represent time and columns represent individuals. I want to turn it into into long panel data format in pandas in an efficient manner, as the DataFames are rather large. I would like to avoid looping. Here is an example: The following DataFrame:

```
      id    1    2
date              
20150520  3.0  4.0
20150521  5.0  6.0
```

should be transformed into:

```
date        id        value
20150520    1         3.0
20150520    2         4.0
20150520    1         5.0
20150520    2         6.0
```

Speed is what's really important to me, due to the data size. I prefer it over elegance if there is a tradeoff. Although I suspect I mam missing a rather simple function, pandas should be able to handle that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df)
            1    2
date              
20150520  3.0  4.0
20150521  5.0  6.0

df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['date','id','value']
print (df)
       date id  value
0  20150520  1    3.0
1  20150520  2    4.0
2  20150521  1    5.0
3  20150521  2    6.0
```

---

```
print (df)
id          1    2
date              
20150520  3.0  4.0
20150521  5.0  6.0

df = df.stack().reset_index(name='value')
print (df)
       date id  value
0  20150520  1    3.0
1  20150520  2    4.0
2  20150521  1    5.0
3  20150521  2    6.0
```

Comment: This is both correct and faster than the other proposed soution

Answer (score 2):

using `melt`

```
pd.melt(df.reset_index(),
        id_vars='date',
        value_vars=['1', '2'],
        var_name='Id')
```

[image]

---

EDIT:
Because OP wants fast ;-)

```
def pir(df):
    dv = df.values
    iv = df.index.values
    cv = df.columns.values
    rc, cc = df.shape
    return pd.DataFrame(
        dict(value=dv.flatten(),
             id=np.tile(cv, rc)),
        np.repeat(iv, cc))
```

Comment: Thanks@piRSquared, this indeed works but the accepted solution is 1.25 times faster.

Comment: @jezrael's answer is what I'd recommend.  Sometimes I'll post an alternative solution because it may still be useful for others... or even you.  I find other poster's solutions invaluable.  pandas/numpy often has many solutions, some of which are faster in some circumstances and slower in others.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, much appreciated I will keep this alternative option in mind

Comment: @splinter I've update post with faster solution.  Keep in mind, you will almost always get a different style of response if you state in your question that speed/efficiency is your goal.

Answer (score 1):

the function you are looking for is

```
df.reset_index()
```

you can then rename your columns using

```
df.columns = ['date', 'id', 'value']
```

Comment: That wouldn't work. Apparently I also need the stack function as mentioned above. Thanks though.